# Importing useGLTF from '@react-three/drei/useGLTF' cause Module not found:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, module, react-three-fiber

I have installed the react three fiber
here's a dependences

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-three/drei": "^3.0.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
"drei": "^2.2.21",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"react-spring": "^8.0.27",
"react-three-fiber": "^5.3.18",
"three": "^0.125.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
```

},

and I run `npm i drei`

after it, I tried to import  useGLTF

```
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei/useGLTF'
```

and I got error

```
./src/Components/Three/Scene.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-three/drei/useGLTF' in 'D:\coding\react\mincraft\src\Components\Three'
```

I decided to check the file manually inside @react-three/drei/useGLTF
but there's no name such as useGLTF

do I need to run something else ?

Answer (score 2):

Damn. after some time I found useGLTF inside drei/core/useGLTF.

```
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei/core/useGLTF'
```

Comment: you should be able to do import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei' as it must tree-shake the rest away.

Comment: yes everyone is importing from '@react-three/drei'  . I still don't understand why mine did not work that way.

Comment: the same with me.. mine says Module not found: Can't resolve 'three/examples/jsm/libs/meshopt_decoder.module.js'

Comment: @Jay-RJosephGabunada probably path error, I suggest search "meshopt_decoder.module.js" this file manually three/examples/jsm/libs in this location

Comment: Having the same issue here with drei and r3f on CSB "Could not find module in path: 'three/examples/jsm/libs/meshopt_decoder.module.js' relative to '/node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/useGLTF.js'"

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install three`.
That worked for me

Comment: `three` is already installed, look at the `package.json` provided